# Xamarin iOS NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains cannot be found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Was writing some Xamarin.iOS code to creates a list of directory search paths.

**objective-c version :**

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

and I realized that `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` is not available in Xamarin iOS, first, I thought it was that I was doing something wrong but then I googled for it and found literally nothing in relation to xamarin.ios is it that there is a C# equivalent of `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` that I am unaware of? Or what exactly am I missing?

**My code in C# so far:**

```
NSArray paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, true);
```

**Note:** There is no Quick Action available for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not rare for Xamarin iOS methods to have a bit different names than associated obj c methods, so sometimes one has to look at the sources of xamarin macios bindings. I found a static method [**GetDirectories**](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/master/src/Foundation/NSSearchPath.cs)   which uses the objc method which you are after:

```
public static class NSSearchPath
{
    public static string[] GetDirectories (NSSearchPathDirectory directory, NSSearchPathDomain domainMask, bool expandTilde = true)
    {
        return NSArray.StringArrayFromHandle (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains ((nuint)(ulong)directory, (nuint)(ulong)domainMask, expandTilde));
    }

    [DllImport (Constants.FoundationLibrary)]
    static extern IntPtr NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (nuint directory, nuint domainMask, bool expandTilde);
}
```

Example usage:

```
string[] directories = NSSearchPath.GetDirectories(NSSearchPathDirectory.UserDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.All);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it and get back to you